# How do i place a 16bit bit image into Adobe Illustrator without it converting it to 8bit?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

How do i place a 16bit bit image into Adobe Illustrator without it converting it to 8bit?

i have "Googled" all over the web, but i cant find anything on changing color depth of a AI file to 16bit

BTW the file i'm working on is for web so it's RGB.

Comment: In what format are you working?

Comment: Why do you need 16-bit in Illustrator?

Comment: @Scott i am placing psd's that are 16bit and when i export it i want it to be 16bit

Comment: But... "i'm working on is for web" the "web" doesn't support 16bit either... There's little incentive to work in 16bit once you need Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott It will also be used for print but it must be in RGB. Other then that i would just like to know for other projects.

Comment: Can not be done (well you might be ble to clobber up a 16 bit pdf and eps that can be linked wont do you any good tough as it will screw up at some point like pdf export). Anyway unless you work for film theres not much point in 16 bit images for print.